# xterm error loading font: which font package includes iso10646 fonts?

Tags: x11, fonts, xterm, amazon-ec2, amazon-linux

Everytime I start an xterm on my Amazon Linux release 2 (Karoo) server, I get an error complaining about a missing font:

xterm: cannot load font '-misc-fixed-medium-r-semicondensed--13-120-75-75-c-60-iso10646-1'

I have every x11 font package I can find loaded (via "yum install xorg-x11-font*" as suggested elsewhere) including xorg-x11-fonts-misc-7.5-9.amzn2.noarch, which should contain the iso10646 font and yet it still can't find the iso10646 font.  Where can I find this font or, alternatively, tell my xterm not to use it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [xterm can not load font "-misc-fixed-medium-r-semicondensed--13-120-75-75-c-60-iso10646-1"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/407710/xterm-can-not-load-font-misc-fixed-medium-r-semicondensed-13-120-75-75-c-60-i)

Comment: The answer to that question does not state where I can find the iso10646 font to stop getting the error.  It sees that the iso10646 font is being used in /usr/share/X11/app-defaults/XTerm for *VT100.utf8Fonts.font but then doesn't list that font in the font files used section...

Comment: The example shows the "misc" font which provides it in Red Hat.  Your question did not mention that you have that installed.

Comment: Yeah, I see now that it shows that the font should be provided by /usr/share/X11/fonts/misc/6x13.pcf.gz
I downloaded and ran your script (thanks for that!) on my ec2 instance and it shows the same thing... That font is found in 6x13.pcf.gz which is provided by package xorg-x11-fonts-misc-7.5-9.amzn2.noarch.
But I still get the error launching xterm... so frustrating.

Comment: Bitmap fonts are handled by the (possibly remote) X server, unlike TrueType fonts (done on the client side).  Connecting to Amazon (AWS?), I'd assume your X server is not on the machine where xterm's running from.

Comment: Yes, I am connecting remotely and using XMing as my local X server... so maybe it's my local X server that can't find the font?  Interesting.

Answer (score 2):

With @ThomasDickey 's help I was able to find the solution to this problem.  Namely, the local X-Server I was running (Xming) didn't have the errant font installed.  I downloaded and installed xming-fonts (from https://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/files/Xming-fonts/7.7.0.10/Xming-fonts-7-7-0-10-setup.exe/download) on my local node (*not* the node that was running xterm) and that fixed the error.

So xterm wasn't complaining that *it* couldn't find the font, it was the local X Server that was complaining.